# Regression tables for robust regressions in R

Tags: r, formatting, regression, pretty-print

I've had some success using mtable from the `memisc` package to pretty-print results (APSR-style) for several regressions side-by-side, but I'm having trouble getting the same command to work for models fit with `lrm()` from the `MASS` package and `lmrob()` from the `robustbase` package.

Works great:

```
lm0 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75,              data = LifeCycleSavings)
lm1 <- lm(sr ~                 dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)
lm2 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)

mtable123 <- mtable("Model 1"=lm0,"Model 2"=lm1,"Model 3"=lm2)
```

Fails at the `mtable()` command `("Error in qt(p, df, lower.tail, log.p): Non-numeric argument to mathematical function")`:

```
rlm0 <- rlm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75,              data = LifeCycleSavings)
rlm1 <- rlm(sr ~                 dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)
rlm2 <- rlm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)

mtable123 <- mtable("Model 1"=rlm0, "Model 2"=rlm1, "Model 3"=rlm2)
```

Fails at the `mtable()` command (`"Error in UseMethod("getSummary"): no applicable method for 'getSummary' applied to an object of class "lmrob""`):

```
lmrob0 <- lmrob(sr ~ pop15 + pop75,              data = LifeCycleSavings)
lmrob1 <- lmrob(sr ~                 dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)
lmrob2 <- lmrob(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)

mtable123 <- mtable("Model 1"=lmrob0, "Model 2"=lmrob1, "Model 3"=lmrob2)
```

I'm open to suggestions that don't involve mtable, but I'm looking for plain-text or tab-separated output (in other words, not LaTeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation at `?getSummary` in the **memisc** package describes how you can extend the `mtable` function to be used on other model types.

In particular, you need to create an appropriate method for `getSummary` and then create a summary template using `setSummaryTemplate`. So, for instance, something like this works:

```
getSummary.rlm <- function(obj, alpha = 0.5,...){
    obj_summary <- summary(obj)

    coefficients <- cbind(coef(obj_summary),dt(coefficients[,3],df = obj_summary$df))
    #You can add the CI code yourself, this is a placeholder:
    coefficients <- cbind(coefficients,matrix(NA,nrow(coefficients),2))
    colnames(coefficients) <- c('est','se','stat','p','lwr','upr')

    sumstat <- c(sigma = obj_summary$sigma,df = obj_summary$df[2],stddev = obj_summary$stddev)

    return(list(coef = coefficients,sumstat = sumstat))
}

setSummaryTemplate(rlm = c(sigma = "($sigma:#)",df = "($df:#)",stddev = "($stddev:#)"))

mtable123 <- mtable("Model 1"=rlm0,"Model 2"=rlm1,"Model 3"=rlm2)
mtable123

Calls:
Model 1: NULL
Model 2: NULL
Model 3: NULL

=======================================
             Model 1  Model 2  Model 3 
---------------------------------------
(Intercept)  28.528*   6.497** 28.945**
             (7.535)  (1.225)  (7.602) 
pop15        -0.434**          -0.473**
             (0.149)           (0.150) 
pop75        -1.595            -1.655  
             (1.059)           (1.120) 
dpi                    0.001*  -0.000  
                      (0.001)  (0.001) 
ddpi                   0.462    0.385  
                      (0.206)  (0.203) 
---------------------------------------
sigma          3.739    4.383    3.523 
df            47.000   47.000   45.000 
stddev         3.998    4.098    3.931 
=======================================
```

Comment: Wow--this is exactly what I needed! Thanks for the code as well.

One question: Line 4 should be "coefficients <- cbind(coef(obj_summary),dt(coef(obj_summary)[,3],df = obj_summary$df))", right?